# Get data faster from databasse

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

My site having a more than 1.5 million records and my question is the how may i fetch record fast.

i am spending so much time to find the way for it finally find out the one way which is to apply the indexing on the field. also try to apply on that it's better result than before.

but still it taking to much time to getting data from the database can any one tell me other technique or trick which i applied on that so it give me much better performance. and my site is built in laravel 4.2.

You can see also my query like below

```
     $result = DB::table('bussiness')
                ->select(array('bussiness.*', DB::raw('COUNT(complaintreport.id) as reported')))
                ->where('bussiness.is_approved', 1)
                ->where('bussiness.status', 1)
                ->where(function($sql) use ($data) {
                    $sql->where('bussiness.bussiness_name', 'like', '%' . Str::upper($data['searchstring']) . '%');
                    $sql->orWhere('bussiness.trading_name', 'like', '%' . Str::upper($data['searchstring']) . '%');
                })
                ->leftjoin('complaintreport', 'complaintreport.bussiness_id', '=', 'bussiness.id')
                ->groupby('bussiness.id')
                ->get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show the code of the slow query in order for others to propose ways to improve it.

Comment: @nicholai : Thanks for reply and can you please check it out my question again i have updated with my query structure. which i have used.

Comment: That is not really a query.  It would be better to get the actual SQL being generated by that construct... and then use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to review the server's query plan... but certainly `WHERE column LIKE '%search_string%'` is *always* going to be a slower query because indexes provide very little benefit.  The `%` at the beginning prevents any index on the referenced column from being used, if there is one.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot : ok than what is the batter option for using other than % in my query can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a full table scan with no way to speed it up.

Look into `FULLTEXT(bussiness_name, trading_name)` indexing as a *much* faster way to search for *words*.  You would need `MATCH (bussiness_name, trading_name) AGAINST("$data['searchstring']" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

If `status` is rarely 1 and `is_approved` is rarely 1, then this would help: `INDEX(status, is_approved)`.

You should also protect yourself from SQL injection by escaping the searchstring.

Comment: @rich james : thanks for reply i already applied this thing in my code now and it giving better performance than before but it still not giving me satisfactory response. can you please give me some other trick which you know about it than please let me know.

Comment: Let's see the `SELECT`, `EXPLAIN`, and `CREATE TABLE`.